# PHP Compare two arrays

Tags: php

Say I have two arrays:

```
     $a = a,b,c;
     $b = a,b;
```

When I compare this array output should be `c`.

Omit the common values in both array.

Comment: [`array_diff`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Compare to values of two arrays in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2631520/compare-to-values-of-two-arrays-in-php)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I compare two arrays and list differences in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/504616/how-can-i-compare-two-arrays-and-list-differences-in-php)

Answer (score 3):

The quick answer:

```
array_merge(array_diff($a, $b), array_diff($b, $a));
```

array-diff($a, $b) will only extract values from $a which are not in $b.

The idea is to merge the differences.

And another way to achieve your goal might be:

```
function array_unique_merge() {
        return array_unique(call_user_func_array('array_merge', func_get_args()));
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the PHP [array_diff](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php) function.

```
$a = a,b,c;
$b = a,b;
$c = array_diff($a,$b);
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, that's not valid PHP - but...

```
$a = array("a","b","c");
$b = array("a","b");
print_r(array_diff($a,$b)); // Array ( [2] => c )
```

Comment: :I did it in the same way but after this i passed to implode,o/p of implode s array.How come?

Answer (score 0):

Just to make things more straighforward

```
$a = array("a","b","c");
$b = array("a","b");
$new_array = array_merge(array_diff($a, $b), array_diff($b, $a));
while (list ($key, $val) = each ($new_array)) {
echo $val;
}
```